# Как в C# правильно обработать повторно выброшенное исключение?

Tags: c#, исключения

Вот код:

```
class ExceptionsDemo
{
    public static void Divide(int x, int y)
    {
        try
        {
            var z = x / y;
        }
        catch (DivideByZeroException ex)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("y равен 0", ex);
        }
    }

    public static void Execute(int x, int y)
    {
        try
        {
            Divide(x, y);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var inner = ex.InnerException;
            Console.WriteLine(inner.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Вызываю вот так:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   ExceptionsDemo.Divide(5, 0);            
}
```

Ожидаю, что повторно выброшенное исключение поймается в Execute, но этого не происходит - программа вылетает, если запустить отладку. Если запустить без режима отладки, то выполняется, а в консоли пишет "Unhandled exception. System.ArgumentException: y равен 0". Почему оно unhandled, если я его ловлю?

Если изменить вызов вот так:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        ExceptionsDemo.Divide(5, 0);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Catch в main");
    }
}
```

тогда повторное исключение ловится в catch мейна.

Comment: А вы же его не вызывает, как оно должно быть там поймано?

Comment: В Execute-то поймается, только вызываете вы Divide

Comment: Как-то перемудрили с исключениями. Зачем ловить и перебрасывать если можно сразу в Execute ловить DivideByZeroException? Или уж если кастомное исключение хочется - можно проверять аргумент на 0 до деления и кидать свое исключение.

Comment: @yolosora это синтетический пример, просто чтобы посмотреть разные варианты оформления и какой путь проходит программа, а деление на ноль выбрано как простой способ получить ошибку.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как правильно написали в комментариях, вы не вызываете метод `Execute`, поэтому исключение не ловится. Если вызывать `Execute` вместо `Divide`, то должно пойматься:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   ExceptionsDemo.Execute(5, 0);            
}
```

Comment: А метод `Divide()` вообще я бы предложил автору сделать `private`, чтобы не путаться.

Comment: @aepot да я вообще как увидел в чем дело, мне даже неловко стало. В самом деле, ловлю в Execute, а вызываю Divide, и еще удивляюсь, а что же оно не ловит...

Comment: @DenisDyatlov поэтому заранее думайте, какой метод будет публичный, а какой приватный. Методы, не предназначенные к использованию снаружи класса, надо прятать в обязательном порядке. Это убережет вас от подобного рода ошибок и сделает процесс разработки удобнее.